# How to create nested list according to value in the list?

Tags: python-2.7, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have 2 lists, that I would like to use to create a nested list:

```
list1=['a','a','b','c','d','d']
list2=['a1','a2','b','c','d1','d2']

result = [['a1','a2'],['b'],['c'],['d1','d2']]
```

meaning that I want to create one sublist per item from list1 (eg. here 4 lists, one for a, one for b, one for c, and last one for d); and the list "result" storing the values from list2. I never did something like that until now, I've read about comprehension lists, but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: create a dictionary where keys are values form list1 and values are from list2. If you see same key again, then append to the value from the list2. Finally create a list of values of dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1=['a','a','b','c','d','d']
list2=['a1','a2','b','c','d1','d2']

d = {}
for key, value in zip(list1, list2):
    if !key in d:
        d[key] = []
    d[key].append(value)

d.values()

[['a1', 'a2'], ['c'], ['b'], ['d1', 'd2']]
```

Comment: Thank you Vishal! Working fine.